# how to make 499 error or close a request of a website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm making a chrome extension and i don't know how to close a request (or make 499 error). I tried to analyze the code of some "web protectors" but I didn't find anything that would help me. I did a search in google but also without success. How to make this?

I tried replacing all the content on the website but of course it didn't work.

Comment: xmlhttprequest? fetch? what sort of request? what initiates the request? why do you want to close the request?

Comment: I'm trying to make a "website blocker"(antivirus for web) and i want to block all of the page

Comment: Extensions can use declarativeNetRequest API to block requests, there are many examples. If that's not what you want please describe the requirements in more detail.